# retrieve the object type of a jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selector that sometimes selects the `window` object, sometimes not. How can i determine from the selector if is indeed selecting the `window` object?

```
var selector = null

if(certain condition is met){
    selector = $('#myDiv');
} else {
    selector = $(window);
}


if($.isWindow(selector)){ //<-- does not work because the object is a jQuery selector

    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index notation to get the DOM element and use that for your test: `$.isWindow(selector[0])`

Or you could use the get() function: `$.isWindow(selector.get(0))`